# Как вычислить производительность функции php?

Tags: php, производительность

Только изучаю php. Интересует вопрос как узнать насколько быстро выполняется та или иная функция или запрос к БД.
Есть ли для этого какие-то методы самого языка или нужно писать/искать дополнительную утилиту?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200214/how-can-i-measure-the-speed-of-code-written-in-php

Comment: А для профилирования запросов к БД у каждой БД есть свои средства. Начиная с [EXPLAIN](https://habrahabr.ru/post/31129/) для MySQL.

Comment: @KoVadim, PinkTux, большое спасибо! То, что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для профилирования Sql можно использовать explain как вам написали в комментариях, для php функций можно засекать время до начала работы функции и после того как отработает функция. Если брать больше чем один скрипт или один запрос, например весь проект, то можно использовать Xdebug + KCachegrind
https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler
https://habrahabr.ru/post/31468/
также можете использовать memory_get_usage(http://php.net/manual/ru/function.memory-get-usage.php) функцию и аналогичные, чтобы следить за используемой памятью

для mysql http://www.profilesql.com/ru/